# Cómo puedo setear diferentes colores para diferentes tipos de comentarios en Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio, vscode

Tengo esta configuración para los comentarios en Visual Studio 2017:

1. Dos barras `//` (verde oscuro en la imagen adjunta) para indicar "comentarios normales".
2. Tres barras `///` (verde claro) para notas y títulos especiales que quiero resaltar.

Encuentro que esta técnica es muy útil para mantener un código más limpio y legible, y me gustaría aplicar la misma lógica (con configuraciones de color similares) en Visual Studio Code, pero no logro entender cómo hacerlo.

Puede parecer trivial, pero para mí es importante. ¿Podrían ayudarme con esto?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial del sitio es el Español, asi que debes o bien traducir la pregunta, o bien hacerla en [so]

Comment: You should probably be asking questions in spanish here. Having said that, your question has already been answered over here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45195023/how-do-i-change-color-of-comments-in-visual-studio-code :) Si queres la podes preguntar de vuelta aquí pero en español así te puede ayudar más gente o sino preguntarla en ingles en [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) :)

Comment: Gracias bejamin por tu respuesta, pero eso noe s lo que estaba buscando. No quiero saber cómo cambiar simplemente el color de los comentarios, sino poder tener 2 tipos de comentarios diferenciados por 2 colores diferentes, como muestra la imagen (verde claro y verde obscuro). Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Comment: Sí, perdón, me confundí. Muchas gracias por hacerlo notar @Pikoh

Comment: Echa un vistazo a [esta extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.docomment), creo que es justo lo que pedías

Answer (score 0):

lo que tu dices en las opciones por defecto ya existe, para cambiar y hacer mas notorio el cambio de color tienes la opción aquí

`Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors`

Para cambiar el color de `//` és `Comment`

Para cambiar el color de `///` és `XML Doc Comment`

A parte tienes estos tipos de comentario:

- Comment
- CSS Comment
- HTML Comment
- VB Xml Comment
- VB XML Doc Comment
- VB Xml Doc Tag
- VB Script Comment
- XAML Comment
- XML Comment
- XML Doc Comment
- XML Doc Tag

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]